# RMySQL::dbListConnections no longer exists?

Tags: r, rmysql, r-dbi

So, I've just starting messing around with the development version of [RMySQL](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL) -- v.0.11.0.9000 -- and I've noticed that when trying to check if I had any open connections -- using [DBI](https://github.com/rstats-db/DBI) v. 0.3.1.9008 -- I get the error:

```
> DBI::dbListConnections(MySQL())
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
 unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbListConnections’ for signature ‘"MySQLDriver"’
```

Indicating that `RMySQL` no longer extends `dbListConnections` for its driver (pardon my adhoc jargon)... Am I right in interpreting this as we no longer need to clean up our DB connections?

If not, how are we supposed to clean up after ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to cleanup after yourself, but it's still recommended. Just `dbDisconnect(con)` when you're done with it.  If you don't happen to have `con` in an easily accessible format, don't worry about it.

Comment: is this the way things are for all of the `rstats-db` packages?

Comment: It is for the dev version of RSQLite, RPostgres and RMySQL. I think it's the correct behaviour for a REPL

Comment: what about for the "not dev" version?